# App detail screen android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a app-details screen in my application, for this best design pattern i can  imagine is default app-detail screen of android, which is shown in screenshot[image]

now here problem is that, i don't know how to create the `"................"` part between those key-value pair, that dotted section should be flexible to capture to increase or shrink as per the size of text on both side

e.g.

scenario 1:

`Total..........2MB`   (10 dots + text)

scenario 2:

`Total........200KB`   (8 dots + text)

so dots gets adjusted as per text size.

Can anybody suggest me how to achieve that, also please if you know some better way(patterns) to show `key-value` pair in app-details scenario, it is most welcome.

Answer (score 2):

It is pretty simple (dummy layout):

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <TextView parentLeft="true"/>
    <TextView parentRight="true"/>
    <Textview background="@drawable/one_dot_repeat"
        toRightOf="@id/firstTextView"
        toLeftOf="@id/secondTextView"
        layout_width="match_parent"> <!-- or any other view -->
</RelativeLayout>
```

Edit: Maybe a 9patch isn't perfect, but you could create a xml where you just add a image with one dot and set repeat="true".

Second edit: A more suitable solution might be to add a [shape](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) as background. The shape could be something like that (untested):

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line" >
    <size
        android:width="500"
        android:height="1" />
    <solid
        android:color="@color/black" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1"
        android:color="@color/white"
        android:dashWidth="1"
        android:dashGap="1" />
</shape>
```

I think you need to tweak the values a bit but it should work.

Comment: Unfortunately this answer wouldn't work, as the 9-patch would stretch, rather than increase the number of dots between the pairs

Comment: Yes, just realized that too, I updated my answer and suggest a repeated bitmap created using xml shape definition

Comment: Yeah, the repeated bitmap solution might work, it's not that elegant, but it would work

Comment: I am open to suggestions. What would be a more elegant solution? The dots aren't typographical dots.

Answer (score 2):

[java.util.Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) to the rescue:

The Formatter can left-justify the text to be printed and you can assign a width to it, so it will fill with spaces the text so that it occupies all of the desired width, then you just need to replace the spaces with the dots. Here is an example:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test
{
        public static final synchronized strictfp void main(String[] args)
        {
                Map<String, Double> myData = new LinkedHashMap<String, Double>();
                myData.put("Total", 24.0);
                myData.put("App", 24.0);
                myData.put("USB storage app", 0.0);
                myData.put("Data", 0.0);
                myData.put("SD card", 0.0);


                for(Map.Entry myEntry : myData.entrySet())
                {
                        Formatter myFormatter = new Formatter();
                        myFormatter.format("%1$-20s%2$15.2fKB", myEntry.getKey(), myEntry.getValue());
                        System.out.println(myFormatter.toString().replace(' ', '.'));
                }
        }
}
```

The interesting part here is the format string:

```
%1$-20s
```

Prints the first argument (1$) left justified (-) with a max width of 20 characters (20) as a string (s).

```
%2$15.2fKB\n
```

Prints the second argument (2$) with a max width of 15 characters (15) and 2 decimal points (.2) as a float (f).

This means that the first value will always be fixed to 20 characters and the second value will always be fixed to 15 characters. Then all the rows will always be 35 characters long + the KB suffix + the decimal point of the float number.

The above code produces the output:

```
Total.........................24.00KB
App...........................24.00KB
USB.storage.app................0.00KB
Data...........................0.00KB
SD.card........................0.00KB
```

TODO: don't overwrite legitimate spaces in the names of the first column ;)

Answer (score 0):

Though I am not Sure, Still it came in my mind that we can also achieve this as follows,

You define total length of string you are going to print/show on screen.

Suppose you define it 20. now u have two cases, let me tell u by an example.

> Str1 = Total
>
> Str2 = 200KB
>
> you can now add another string such as
>
> Str3 ="";
>
> for(i=0;i<(20-str1.length()-str2.length))
>
> str3 +=".";
>
> now u have three strings as "Total", "200KB/20KB" and "dots/...", you can print them with the help of single TextV or multiple TextViews.

u can also try to calculate total length instead of that 20. As i mentioned I am not sure , so please no negative votes :P

Comment: This would work with a fixed-width font, but not with variable width fonts.